# Need guidance in missing value imputation in count variables

Tags: missing-data, poisson-regression, negative-binomial-distribution, data-imputation

I have a few **count** variables that are part of a larger dataset (the rest of the variables are either numerical or ordinal). Their distributions can be seen below.

My goal is to **impute the missing values** in these columns

I am not really sure what model to use to impute each one of them. I have tried Poisson and Negative Binomial regressions but have gotten very poor results (as expected, the data looks terrible), except for the last variable (last graph).

What pipeline should I follow to get better results? Should I transform the data somehow so a regression model fits it better? Are the models I've chosen not suited for these types of variables?

This is my first time imputing data so any guidance is extremely appreciated.

---

[image: Mean and Variance of the features]

[image: Frequencies]